# How should I provide bank statements for an Australian Subclass 600 tourist visa?

Tags: visas, paperwork, australia, tourist-visas

I want to apply for an Australian Subclass 600 tourist visa. According to the [document checklist](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-visa-(subclass-600)-Tourist-Stream-document-checklist) (with commentary below each statement concerning my own situation):

> Your bank statements showing your name as the account holder, all
>   transactions for the past three (3) months and the final balance of
>   the accounts (name and recent date must be included on the
>   statements);

The bank statements are in Spanish and are denominated in Chilean Pesos (CLP).

> Translating your documents
>
> Any document in a language other than English must be accompanied by a
>   certified English translation

Does this requirement *include* the bank statements or is it referencing passports, birth certificates and such?

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Why would it not include bank statements?

Comment: The "documents" part, it's not an official document, but I don't know maybe it's a silly question, what should you translate, everythings? including the description of the last 3 months? or just the main stuff, it's kind of confusing to me the translation format.

Comment: @JonathanReez perhaps because bank statements are not official government documents in the same way that passports and birth certificates *are*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**Any** document in a language other than English must be accompanied by a certified English translation."